# Proving basis of $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over some field $F$ is given. Now let $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ be the set of all linear maps from $V$ to $W$. Also let $\dim V=n,\dim W=m$ and $\mathscr{M}(m,n,F)$ be the set of $m\times n$ matrices with entries in $F$. It is not a big challenge to show that $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ and $\mathscr{M}(m,n,F)$ are isomorphic. We use the isomorphism $\varphi$ which maps a linear map to its matrix with respect to some fixed ordered bases of $V$ and $W$ respectively. Now finding the standard basis for $\mathscr{M}(m,n,F)$ is not a big deal. So $\varphi^{-1}$ gives the corresponding bases of $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$. Now it is clear that they are a basis since the map's an isomorphism. But if we didn't know that. And were asked to show that the linear maps thus found form a basis, then how would we do it? This question is self-made so may be not too good. But I am having trouble in proving the linear maps $$T_{ij}(v_k)=\left\{\begin{array}{c}w_j\qquad k=i\\\\0\qquad \text{otherwise}\end{array} \right\|$$
are generators as well as linearly independent.
Note here $(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n)$ is an ordered basis of $V$ and $(w_1,w_2,\dots,w_m)$ is an ordered basis of $W$. Can someone prove it? Thanks.

Comment: Suppose that $\sum \alpha_{ij}T_{ij}=0$. Evaluate at $v_k$ to get linear dependence equations of the $w_k$, use they are linearly independent to get $\alpha_{ij}=0$ throughout.

Comment: Oh yeah the linear independence seems to be doable. But the generator part is still tricky. I am having trouble guessing what the co-efficients $\displaystyle \sum_{i}\sum_{j}\alpha_{ij}T_{ij}=T$ should give this equation. Any hints? Thanks. I don't want a full solution, just a hint would be good enough, thanks a lot.

Comment: $\alpha_{ij}$ is the $j$-th coefficient of $T(v_i)$ in the basis of the $w_k$ (you might have to swap $i$ and $j$; but you get the idea.)